# Codeigniter subdomain routing

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, custom-url

I'm trying to setup a blog script on a website running on the CodeIgniter framework. I want do this without making any major code changes to my existing website's code. I figured that creating a sub domain pointing to another Controller would be the cleanest method of doing this.

The steps that I took to setup my new `Blog` controller involved:

1. Creating an A record pointing to my server's ip address.
2. Adding new rules to CodeIgniter's `routes.php` file.

Here is what I came up with:

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'blog.notedu.mp':
        $route['default_controller'] = "blog"; 
        $route['latest'] = "blog/latest";
        break;
    default:
        $route['default_controller'] = "main";
        break;
}
```

This should point `blog.notedu.mp` and `blog.notedu.mp/latest` to my `blog` controller.

Now here is the problem...

Accessing `blog.notedu.mp` or `blog.notedu.mp/index.php/blog/latest` works fine, however accessing `blog.notedu.mp/latest` takes me to a 404 page for some reason...

My .htaccess file looks like this (the default for removing index.php from the url):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

And my `Blog` controller contains the following code:

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    public function _remap($method){
        echo "_remap function called.\n";
        echo "The method called was: ".$method;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('../../global/helpers/base');

        $this->load->view('blog');
    }

    public function latest(){
        echo "latest working";
    }

}
```

What am I missing out on or doing wrong here? I've been searching for a solution to this problem for days :(

Comment: do you have htaccess to remove `index.php`?

Comment: I do yes. Should this make a difference?

Comment: Just edited the OP with my htaccess file if it helps.

Comment: Still can't get this working, so started a bounty. You CodeIgniter gurus should be able to earn an easy +50 here ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After 4 days of trial and error, I've finally fixed this issue!

Turns out it was a .htaccess problem and the following rules fixed it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Thanks to everyone that read or answered this question.

Comment: I have a question for you - does notedu.mp/blog and notedu.mp/blog/latest also show your blog?

Answer (score 1):

Does blog.domain.co/blog/latest also show a 404?
maybe you could also take a look at the _remap() function for your default controller.
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#default

Basically, CodeIgniter uses the second segment of the URI to determine which function in the controller gets called. You to override this behavior through the use of the _remap() function.

Straight from the user guide,

> If your controller contains a function named _remap(), it will always
>   get called regardless of what your URI contains. It overrides the
>   normal behavior in which the URI determines which function is called,
>   allowing you to define your own function routing rules.

```
public function _remap($method)
    {
        if ($method == 'some_method')
        {
            $this->$method();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->default_method();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still have the same problem. http://blog.notedu.mp/ triggers the function successfully, but http://blog.notedu.mp/latest throws an apache 404 page (not a CodeIgniter one). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

have a "AllowOverride All" in the configuration file of the subdomain in apache?

without it "blog.notedu.mp/index.php/blog/latest" work perfectly, but "blog.notedu.mp/latest" no

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have the following rule within my sites-enabled file for my domain but still 404. # Give .htaccess full override permissions
  <Directory />
      AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=All,MultiViews
  </Directory>

Answer (score -1):

```
$route['latest'] = "index";
```

means that the URL `http://blog.example.com/latest` will look for an `index()` method in an `index` controller.

You want

```
$route['latest'] = "blog/latest";
```

Codeigniter user guide has a clear explanation about routes [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is actually what I have in my route - I forgot to update this part of the code since my last edit. I added      
$route['(:any)'] = "blog/latest"; as a test also, but I still get a 404. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you echo out `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to verify it's what you expect (blog.notedu.mp)? Also, can you check error_log and access_log?